# How to manually make sure the database schema is right?

Tags: 7, updating

I updated my drupal installation to 7.7 and now it keeps giving me an alert that the database schema needs to be updated for views and google analytics. I click on it and follow the onscreen instructions and there are NO errors, and the message is still there. Can I manually make sure the schema is up to date and deactivate the warning message?

Comment: You will need to provide more information to get any help. What alert? What directions?

Answer (score 3):

The [Schema](http://drupal.org/project/schema) module gives you a lot of different tools to handle your schema; for example, it checks whether your schema is in sync with your database.

Answer (score 1):

Usually, what you have to do to update the database schema after core, module or theme upgrades is to call `/update.php` in your browser, as documented here:

[Updating modules: Run update.php](https://www.drupal.org/node/250790#update)

If you use drush, you can do the same with the following command as per the [drush documentation](http://www.drush.org/#updatedb):

```
  drush updatedb
```